# Dockerization php-yii2 basic with mysql: migrations connection refused

Tags: php, docker, yii2

My root project is `company-yii2-blog`

The docker-compose.yml looked like this:

```
version: "3"

# Services
services:

    # NGINX Service
    webserver-nginx:
        build:
            context:  "./nginx"
            dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
        container_name: webserver-nginx
        ports:
            - "${WEB_SERVER_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - "./php/yii2/:/var/www/html"
            - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
            - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
        depends_on:
            - php-yii2
        networks:
            - company-network

    # MYSQL Service
    db:
        build:
            context:  "./mysql/"
            dockerfile:  "Dockerfile"
        container_name: db
        tty: false
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - company-volumes:/var/lib/mysql/
            - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
            - company-network
        ports:
            - ${DB_PORT}:3306

    # PHP App Service
    php-yii2:
        build:
            context:  "./php"
            dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
        container_name: php-yii2
        tty: true
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        env_file: 
            - .env
        volumes:
            - "./php/yii2/:/var/www/html"
        networks:
            - company-network
        depends_on:
            - db

# Docker Networks
networks:
    company-network:
        driver: bridge

# Docker Volumes
volumes:
    company-volumes:
        driver: local
```

Call my IP_ADDRESS in PORT 80, everything is running fine in web browser.
But the problem is, when I use the migrations. Yii2 said that connection is refused.

```
dzil@jarvis:~/.../company-yii2-blog$ docker-compose exec php-yii2 php yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.34)

Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused'

in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:635
```

So, to check if the database is running well, I check it out like this.

```
dzil@jarvis:~/.../company-yii2-blog$ docker exec -t -i db /bin/bash
root@265c54d84892:/# mysql -u dev -p
    Enter password: 
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 2
    Server version: 5.7.30-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

    Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.

    Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

    mysql> show databases;
    +--------------------+
    | Database           |
    +--------------------+
    | information_schema |
    | blog               |
    +--------------------+
    2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is tHe .env file

```
# ENVIRONMENT
ENV=local 

# WEBSERVER NGINX
WEB_SERVER_PORT=80

# DB MYSQL
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=13306
DB_NAME=blog
DB_DSN=mysql:host=db;port=13306;dbname=blog
DB_ROOT_USER=root
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
DB_USER=dev
DB_PASSWORD=dev

# PHP YII2 APP
APP_NAME=Blog
```

This is configuration of Yii2 db

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => getenv('DB_DSN'),
    'username' =>  getenv('DB_USER') ,
    'password' =>  getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',

    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    //'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    //'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    //'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

Please, Any help it so appreciated.

Comment: you have mentioned 13306 as db port number. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: Yes, The default port 3306 is have running in my localhost. So I decide to use 13306 to prevent conflict.

Comment: Can you share your yii config ?

Comment: You mean config/db.php or config/web.php ?

Comment: Share the config/db.php

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212754/discussion-between-nitesh-morajkar-and-fadly-dzil).